# I'm not able to connect with SSH because of SUID warning

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, operating-systems, arm

When I try to connect with another machine, after this command below:

```
user1@host1:~$ ssh user2@host2
user2@host2's password:
```

I receive:

```
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
passwd: must be suid to work properly
Connection to host2 closed.
user1@host1:~$
```

- host1 is Ubuntu OS machine
- host2 is Buildroot OS machine

Obviously I've changed my password, but it didn't help.

What is wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: You were about to change the password on host2? (Your post said "hanged" and I think you meant "changed" but maybe you mean "mucked up"? If you want to reset and create a new sshkey you can delete the lines corresponding to host2 in `.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: @beroe: I just want to get access to host2 (with Buildroot) via ssh, but it's just sending this warning and my connection gets closed. I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION:

The source of the problem is the date on my ARM board. This is the reason that the 'password has expired'.

To set up correct date, use:

```
# date -s '[current date]'
```

command on an ARM board, and:

```
# hwclock -w
```

to keep date settings on the hardware.

Comment: thanks, it worked but is there any more info /link on this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have physical access to the box you can fix it as root, without - probably not unless you have another user account on the box that isn't in enforced password change and that can sudo or su to root

Comment: kevinhunlty: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Do you have physical access to the machine? Are you able to login directly to the console?

Comment: kevinhuntly: Thank you, but problem solved (below).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have multiple problems in Your RootFS.

- Your "passwd" executable does not seem suid root
- Your user setup seems in disabled state.

In this condition I do not think You can fix it via ssh.
Do You have access to any form of console (e.g.: serial)?

How did You create (or where did You get) Your RootFS?

If You have access to console try:

- log directly as root
- "passwd username"
- enter a new password
- try again via ssh
- fix /usr/bin/passwd permissions (details depending of busybox usage or not)

Comment: MCon: This is the result: http://dpaste.com/1F1CEWH